Why do some Unicode characters look different depending on preceding text?
Why is the emoji presentation of certain Unicode characters such as 0x23F8 and 0x23ED in the HTML code below affected by whether certain characters such as 0x275A are present much earlier on the same line of text?
I thought that only an immediately subsequent variation selector (which is absent here) can affect the emoji presentation as described here on unicode.org.
Is this a bug in Chrome? Here's the code:


&#x275A;123&#x23F8;&#x23ED;
<br>
123&#x23F8;&#x23ED;



On Chrome, this renders as:

On Firefox, this looks different:

On a related note, the variation selector 0xFE0F works, but 0xFE0E works only in Firefox, not in Chrome:


&#x275A;123&#x23F8;&#xFE0F;&#x23ED;&#xFE0F;
<br>
123&#x23F8;&#xFE0E;&#x23ED;&#xFE0E;




In Chrome and Firefox on Mac, I am getting the same display in both browsers for each of the respective snippets - the first one renders same as your Firefox screenshot shows in Chrome as well, and the second one shows the "blue square" buttons in both browsers.

@C3roe Does the second snippet show four blue squares? In that case 0xFE0E doesn't work on Mac, not even in Firefox.

No, blue squares only in the first line, but in Chrome and Firefox both.

Thanks! So both weird behaviors (being affected by 0x275A and not by 0xFE0E) are specific to Chrome on Windows, not Mac, not Firefox.

It is not Unicode, but a choice of font makers (context is important for fonts). Note: maybe there is also some reference on Unicode standard (or other documents) about recommendation on how to implement emoji in fonts)

@Giacomo Are you saying that this is due to contextual alternates? Why would font makers introduce such a weird rule?

This is probably not a font issue. A likely factor is that these strings do not have any  strong-script characters. What happens if you change the first line to the following?
❚A123⏸⏭

@PeterConstable The special characters then still look the same as without the "A". (I clicked "Copy snippet to answer" and experimented in the draft.) What do you mean by "strong-script characters"?

U+23F8 and U+23ED have by default text presentation rather than emoji presentation, unless VS16 is applied. What is seen will vary across browsers and platforms and I suspect is based on font fallback for each text run. On macOS Chrome and Edge are using Apple Color Emoji for all instances of these two characters. Firefox uses a text font, and only uses an Emoji font if U+FE0F is used. This may be a bug or a design feature in Chrome and Edge.

@C3roe I get different results to you on macOS with Firefox because of how font fallback works in Firefox and what fonts i have installed.
